# pg_dump --exclude-table not working on one specific table

Tags: postgresql, backup, postgresql-9.6

Wanting to exclude a few very large table in a `pg_dump`, I use the -T option multiple times, like this:

```
pg_dump --clean clientportal -T article_plain -T callstats -T cdrviewer_cdr -T calls -T cdrviewer_datasource -T django_sesssion -T django_admin_log
```

`article_plain` however still gets included in the dump.  Using `--schema-only` here for demonstration purposes:

```
postgres@server:~/bin$ pg_dump -s --clean clientportal -T article_plain -T callstats -T cdrviewer_cdr -T calls -T cdrviewer_datasource -T django_sesssion -T django_admin_log | grep article_plain
ALTER TABLE ONLY otrs.article_plain DROP CONSTRAINT fk_article_plain_create_by_id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY otrs.article_plain DROP CONSTRAINT fk_article_plain_change_by_id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY otrs.article_plain DROP CONSTRAINT fk_article_plain_article_id_id;
DROP INDEX otrs.article_plain_article_id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY otrs.article_plain DROP CONSTRAINT article_plain_pkey;
ALTER TABLE otrs.article_plain ALTER COLUMN id DROP DEFAULT;
DROP SEQUENCE otrs.article_plain_id_seq;
DROP TABLE otrs.article_plain;
-- Name: article_plain; Type: TABLE; Schema: otrs; Owner: sg1admin
CREATE TABLE article_plain (                                                 <----- there is article_plain
ALTER TABLE article_plain OWNER TO sg1admin;
...
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

Including the schema fixed it. The other tables were in the public schema but `article_plain` was in a schema of it's own:

```
postgres@server:~/bin$ pg_dump -s --clean clientportal -T otrs.article_plain -T callstats -T cdrviewer_cdr -T calls -T cdrviewer_datasource -T django_sesssion -T django_admin_log | grep article_plain
DROP SEQUENCE otrs.article_plain_id_seq;
-- Name: article_plain_id_seq; Type: SEQUENCE; Schema: otrs; Owner: sg1admin
CREATE SEQUENCE article_plain_id_seq
ALTER TABLE article_plain_id_seq OWNER TO sg1admin;
-- Name: article_plain_id_seq; Type: ACL; Schema: otrs; Owner: sg1admin
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE article_plain_id_seq TO sg1;
```

Answer (score 0):

the use of the below of pg_dump.exe will give you exclusive pattern of tables in a given database.

```
pg_dump.exe -h localhost -d database -W -U username -p 5XX2 -T m_19* -T m_200* -T m_201* -f dbsave.sql
```

where the tables excluded are m_19*, m_200* and m_201 etc.